# CSS: Lining ::before content to middle of element

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a stylized "quote" element, and would like to automatically insert the quote icon in the top middle of the element.

The problem is that I can't get the icon to line up right in the middle, especially when the browser is resized. Also, the beginning of the `pullquote` content starts too far to the right, as it's left room for the `::before` icon, even though it's positioned elsewhere.

```css
.pullquote {
 padding: 1em;
 text-align: center;
  border-top: 2px dashed #ccc;
 border-bottom: 4px solid #ccc;
}
.pullquote::before {
 content: "\f10d";
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    color: #acacac;
    top: -1.3em;
    left: 50%;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 0 0.6em;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<link rel='stylesheet' href='//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css' type='text/css' media='all' />

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, tibique fastidii ea duo, habeo conceptam ut mea. Esse dicant veritus no ius, lorem iuvaret has cu. Vis at fuisset accusata voluptaria, no unum facer epicurei usu. In ius suas latine offendit. Wisi consequat ea has, id modus aliquid scripserit est. Cu ignota civibus vel, sed diam oratio nusquam ad.</p>

<div class="pullquote">
 This is an amazing quote from someone.
</div>
  
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, tibique fastidii ea duo, habeo conceptam ut mea. Esse dicant veritus no ius, lorem iuvaret has cu. Vis at fuisset accusata voluptaria, no unum facer epicurei usu. In ius suas latine offendit. Wisi consequat ea has, id modus aliquid scripserit est. Cu ignota civibus vel, sed diam oratio nusquam ad.</p>
```

Comment: try to change left:50% by margin-left:50%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To center the quote, absolutely position it relative to the parent, and use `left: 50%;` to put the quote 50% from the left, `top: 0;` to put it flush with the top of the pull quote, and `translate(-50%,-50%);` to move it half of it's own width left and up to center it horizontally and half way across the top of the pull quote.

```css
.pullquote {
  padding: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  border-top: 2px dashed #ccc;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #ccc;
  position: relative;
}
.pullquote::before {
  content: "\f10d";
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  color: #acacac;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 0 0.6em;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

```html
<link rel='stylesheet' href='//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css' type='text/css' media='all' />

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, tibique fastidii ea duo, habeo conceptam ut mea. Esse dicant veritus no ius, lorem iuvaret has cu. Vis at fuisset accusata voluptaria, no unum facer epicurei usu. In ius suas latine offendit. Wisi consequat ea has, id modus aliquid scripserit est. Cu ignota civibus vel, sed diam oratio nusquam ad.</p>

<div class="pullquote">
 This is an amazing quote from someone.
</div>
  
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, tibique fastidii ea duo, habeo conceptam ut mea. Esse dicant veritus no ius, lorem iuvaret has cu. Vis at fuisset accusata voluptaria, no unum facer epicurei usu. In ius suas latine offendit. Wisi consequat ea has, id modus aliquid scripserit est. Cu ignota civibus vel, sed diam oratio nusquam ad.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to set the `position` to `absolute`, and make the left margin a negative value of half the `width`, try this updated snippet:

```css
.pullquote {
  padding: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  border-top: 2px dashed #ccc;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #ccc;
  position: relative;
}
.pullquote::before {
  content: "\f10d";
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  color: #acacac;
  top: -0.5em;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -0.7em;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 0 0.6em;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<link rel='stylesheet' href='//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css' type='text/css' media='all' />

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, tibique fastidii ea duo, habeo conceptam ut mea. Esse dicant veritus no ius, lorem iuvaret has cu. Vis at fuisset accusata voluptaria, no unum facer epicurei usu. In ius suas latine offendit. Wisi consequat ea has, id modus
  aliquid scripserit est. Cu ignota civibus vel, sed diam oratio nusquam ad.</p>

<div class="pullquote">
  This is an amazing quote from someone.
</div>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, tibique fastidii ea duo, habeo conceptam ut mea. Esse dicant veritus no ius, lorem iuvaret has cu. Vis at fuisset accusata voluptaria, no unum facer epicurei usu. In ius suas latine offendit. Wisi consequat ea has, id modus
  aliquid scripserit est. Cu ignota civibus vel, sed diam oratio nusquam ad.</p>
```